# It seems FlushFileBuffers() doesn't set end-of-file (and therefore can lead to corrupted files)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Consider following sequence of calls captured with process monitor:

[image]

Here is what happens here:

1. file is opened
2. 15-bytes file write
3. `FlushFileBuffers()` call is made
4. ... which leads to 4kb file write issued by OS
5. file handle is closed via `Close()`
6. ... which results in `SetEndOfFileInformation()` call which sets end-of-file at 15

This leads me to conclude that pulling network cable (or crashing server, etc) after #4 (but before #6) will lead to corrupted file on the server. And therefore successful `FlushFileBuffers()` call doesn't guarantee file is not corrupted in case of outages.

Which in turn means `Close()` can always fail (even after successful `FlushFileBuffers()`) and therefore can't be tucked away in some destructor. It has always to be an explicit call (unless you already rolling back/unwinding due to some other error).

Am I correct? And if not -- why?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but is [`SetEndOfFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setendoffile) of any use to you?

Comment: @PaulSanders (assuming `SetEndOfFile()` doesn't get cached until `Close()`) do you propose to complement `FlushFileBuffers()` with explicit `SetEndOfFile()`?

Comment: Yes, if it works.  It seems you have the tools to check.

Comment: @PaulSanders Well, this post is about `FlushFileBuffers()` to confirm if it has a problem (which is not given). If there is a problem -- the best workaround would be to close and reopen file (or simply `ReOpenFile()`), not call `SetEndOfFile()`...

Comment: End of file is determined by the size of file instead of data in the file. "[Testing for the End of a File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/testing-for-the-end-of-a-file)" Could you show an actual sample to demonstrate how FlushFileBuffers() corrupts the file?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT No, I was asking if this is the case. But after spending more time in debugger and procmon I found that writes 2 and 4 are different somehow (procmon just doesn't show it) -- first one changes file extent and second one doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. According to further investigation second write (step #4) doesn't change file size.